# woocommerce_new_order action not returning all order details

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook, action

I'm using the **woocommerce_new_order** action to send order details to a Mailchimp list.

```
// Add user to mailchimp list
function add_user_to_mailchimp($order_id) {
    $order = get_post_meta($order_id);

    write_log($order);

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'add_user_to_mailchimp', 1, 1 );
```

An important part to keep in mind is that the user may not necessarily register an account.

The most important part is retrieving the the customers email and sending that through to Mailchimp. I want to achieve this by using

```
get_post_meta($order_id, 'billing_email', true);
```

but this returns an empty value even if I use '_billing_email'.

When I output the $order in the log I get the following output:

```
[17-Jan-2017 07:47:35 UTC] Array
(
     [_wc_customer_order_csv_export_is_exported] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
        )

    [_wc_customer_order_csv_export_customer_is_exported] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
        )

    [_order_key] => Array
        (
            [0] => wc_order_587dcc17ca5f0
        )

    [_order_currency] => Array
        (
            [0] => ZAR
        )

    [_prices_include_tax] => Array
        (
            [0] => yes
        )

    [_customer_ip_address] => Array
        (
            [0] => ::1
        )

    [_customer_user_agent] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0
        )

    [_customer_user] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
        )

    [_created_via] => Array
        (
            [0] => checkout
        )

    [_cart_hash] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4457fd575a37c07e4863ce5610ddb4d2
        )

    [_order_version] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2.6.4
        )

)
```

Am I perhaps using the wrong action hook? All the values to exist in the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changed the action to

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'add_user_to_mailchimp', 1, 1 );
```

This action fires after the post meta is created, which wasn't the case with 'woocommerce_new_order'.

Answer (score 0):

Try below teo hook in which pass order id as argument:

```
woocommerce_thankyou
woocommerce_payment_complete
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it needs to fire even if a payment is not complete yet. My answer above did the trick.

Comment: you can use hook: add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'my_status_pending',  1, 1  ); before payment as well.

Answer (score 0):

> and finaly you can use like it

```
`add_action('template_redirect', [$this, 'paymentRedirect']);`
```

```
    public function paymentRedirect()
    {
        if (is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received')) {
            global $wp;

            $int = filter_var($wp->request, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
            $orderId = str_replace('-', '', $int);

           SomeClass::doSomethink($orderId);
        }
    }
```