# WooCommerce notification with Telegram

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, telegram, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to send notification on WooCommerce new order with Telegram. 
I get almost all the details I want except the products list from order. If I use a shortcode to expose the order details in WordPress, my code is working. When I`m trying to do this in Telegram, product details are not shown anymore.

Here is my code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'telegram_notification',  1, 1  );
function telegram_notification( $order_id ) {

            $order     = wc_get_order( $order_id );


            $text = "*" . __( 'New Order') . "*\n\n";
            $text .= __( 'Order number') . ': ' . $order_id . "\n";
            $text .= __( 'Status') . ': ' . wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ) . "\n";
            $text .= __( 'Date') . ': ' . $order->get_date_modified() . "\n";
            $text .= __( 'Email') . ': ' . $order->get_billing_email() . "\n";
            $text .= __( 'Total price') . ': ' . $order->get_total() . "\n";
            $text .= __( 'Payment method') . ': ' . $order->get_payment_method_title() . "\n";
            $text .= "\n" . __( 'Items') . ':' . "\n";

            foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_data ) {
                $product       = $item_data->get_product();
                $product_name  = $product->get_name();
                $item_quantity = $item_data->get_quantity();
                $item_total    = $this->wc_price( $item_data->get_total() );
                $text          .= $product_name . ' × ' . $item_quantity . ' = ' . $item_total . "\n";
            }


            $xsl = file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot12345:xxxxx-zzzzz/sendMessage?parse_mode=html&chat_id=-1234567890&text=" . $text);
}
```

And here is the outcome in Telegram :

> *New Order*__Order number: 981_Stare: Plată în așteptare_Dată: 2020-12-12T12:12:12 00:00_Email: email@yahoo.com_Total price: 10.00_Payment method: Numerar la livrare__Items:_

And nothing is shown on items...

My WooCommerce version is 4.1.0 and WordPress version 5.4.1

Thank you in advance for your time

Comment: how you solve problem?

Comment: I found solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41691777/woocommerce-new-order-action-not-returning-all-order-details

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get and Loop Over Order Items
foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
   $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
   $variation_id = $item->get_variation_id();
   $product = $item->get_product();
   $name = $item->get_name();
   $quantity = $item->get_quantity();
   $subtotal = $item->get_subtotal();
   $total = $item->get_total();
   $tax = $item->get_subtotal_tax();
   $taxclass = $item->get_tax_class();
   $taxstat = $item->get_tax_status();
   $allmeta = $item->get_meta_data();
   $somemeta = $item->get_meta( '_whatever', true );
   $type = $item->get_type();
}
```